# How to find the percentage change in size for a cylinder/sphere like object?

Tags: spheres

I have an object of more or less unknown shape and I'm trying to find the size change over time.  The object is a cancer tumor and from each scan I get two numbers.

Scan 1:
3.0 x 3.6

Scan 2:
1.5 x 1.3

Eyeballing the numbers I would say it is a >50% reduction.  How do I calculate this in math?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just eyeballing it: $3.0\cdot 3.6 = 10.8$ while $1.5\cdot 1.3 = 1.95$. So it is a $\frac{10.8-1.95}{10.8}\approx 82\%$ reduction.

Comment: If a sphere of diameter about 3.3 is reduced to a sphere of diameter about 1.4, that is about a 92% reduction.